# What is wrong with the below query and how to correct it

Tags: sql, database, oracle, merge, oracle19c

The below oracle query is giving a syntax error. I am not able to correct it. Assuming the table names and the columns and corresponding values are right, what is the wrong in the syntax?

```
MERGE INTO AI_IMAGE_EVENT AIE
USING AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE API
    ON API.IMAGE_ID = '172c86a216304dbwks02'
    AND API.ZONE = '03'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (AI_IMAGE_EVENT_SQID,
    AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SQID,
    AI_EVENT_TYPE,
    AI_PROC_START_TIME,
    AI_PROC_END_TIME,
    AI_IMAGE_SERV_TIME,
    FACILITY_ID,
    ZONE,
    CREATED_DATE,
    CREATED_BY,
    LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY)
    VALUES('910000008201', API.AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SQID, 2, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, null, '68731', 10, SYSDATE, '68731', SYSDATE, '68731')
```

This is the error that I am getting.

> Error at Command Line : 9 Column : 9 Error report - SQL Error:
> ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
> 00969. 00000 -  "missing ON keyword"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I ran the above in sql developer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- the `ON` clause needs parentheses (though the message is unhelpful);
- the `BY API` is spurious, that should just be `WHEN MATCHED THEN`;
- you're doing an insert not an update, so it should be `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN`.

So:

```
MERGE INTO AI_IMAGE_EVENT AIE
USING AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE API
    ON (API.IMAGE_ID = '172c86a216304dbwks02' AND API.ZONE = '03')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (AI_IMAGE_EVENT_SQID,
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eLgmbzQ5) showing the various errors. (The last version still errors, with ORA-00942, because I don't have your tables...)

---

> I need to insert when matched in the source table. If that row is present in the source table, I need to insert into target table.

[The merge sytnax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F__BGBBBIDF) doesn't allow that.

You might be looking for `INSERT ... SELECT ...`, something like:

```
INSERT INTO AI_IMAGE_EVENT (
    AI_IMAGE_EVENT_SQID,
    AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SQID,
    AI_EVENT_TYPE,
    AI_PROC_START_TIME,
    AI_PROC_END_TIME,
    AI_IMAGE_SERV_TIME,
    FACILITY_ID,
    ZONE,
    CREATED_DATE,
    CREATED_BY,
    LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY
)
SELECT '910000008201', API.AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SQID, 2, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, null,
    '68731', 10, SYSDATE, '68731', SYSDATE, '68731'
FROM AI_PRODUCT_IMAGE API
WHERE API.IMAGE_ID = '172c86a216304dbwks02'
AND API.ZONE = '03'
```

Comment: I need to insert when matched in the source table. If that row is present in the source table, I need to insert into target table.

Comment: The [merge syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F__BGBBBIDF) doesn't allow that. Are you actually just looking for `INSERT ... SELECT ...`?

Comment: If the select gives null, I will get NotNullConstraint error. That's why I am going for MERGE statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If there are no matching rows (172c86a216304dbwks02 and 03 in API) then no rows will be inserted - it won't try to insert a row will all nulls. If the matching row has nullk columns then that will be true for the merge too, and either way you can handle that with coalesce, or filter out rows with nulls if you prefer.